# How to configure RDP with TLS in Window 7

Tags: ssl, rdp

I have server and client running OS Window 7 ultimate. I would like to configure so that server and client communicate under TLS.

At server, I go Local Group Policy-> Remote Desktop Host -> Security to enable Secure Layer to TLS1.0.

When I connect the server from client, I did capture the packet using Wireshark, but I never see the TLS setup .

I did google alot regarding how to set up the TLS. It said that the self-signed cert is not trusted from the trusted root CA. Is it because of this so the TLS can't set up?

Comment: Off-topic here. Voting to move to SuperUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wireshark often can't guess the protocol when the protocol changes on the same connection. This is typically the case for most protocols that upgrade to SSL/TLS on the same connection (using STARTTLS-like mechanisms).

If you want to see this, you have to tell Wireshark to decode the packets as SSL/TLS: right-click and choose Decode As -> Transport -> SSL.

This should work even with a self-signed certificate (typically one is generated automatically and configured by default on a Windows 7 Pro machine, for example). In this case, if you want the connection the be secure, you'd need to verify manually that it is the certificate set up on that machine.